# "before_filter :oauth_required" does not work properly for "oauth-plugin"? Gives "Invalid OAuth Request"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am using https://github.com/pelle/oauth-plugin.

When I use "before_filter :oauth_required" at the top of a controller it fails the controller and gives "Invalid OAuth Request" even though when I have authorized the action.  i.e. if I take this line out my controller will work properly, calling the google api via oauth and it works....

Any advice how to fix this?  Or is there another approach I should be using?

Answer (score 0):

The author of the plugin recommends using `oauthenticate` instead of `oauth_required` (see [line 114](https://github.com/pelle/oauth-plugin/blob/master/lib/oauth/controllers/application_controller_methods.rb))

Replace `before_filter :oauth_required` with `oauthenticate :interactive => false` and it'll work.